# Not able to get location setting as AVAILABLE if FakeGPS apps are enabled

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

In my app, i need to check whether user has enabled location setting or not before requesting location updates. The way i'm doing that is exactly like in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings

```
val locationSettingsResult = LocationServices
            .getSettingsClient(application)
            .checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
        locationSettingsResult.addOnSuccessListener {
            buttonLocationUpdates.text = "Location Settings Enabled"
        }
        locationSettingsResult.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            when (exception) {
                is ResolvableApiException -> {
                    buttonLocationUpdates.text = "Resolution Required"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm able to get a success callback from the location services if location is enabled. But if i turn a FakeGPS app ON (keeping the location ON), the failure block is ALWAYS triggered in my app. I expect success callback to be returned in my app even when FakeGPS is ON since i've not turned off my location services.

This is reproducible 100% on Samsun S10 and also on a few other OnePlus phones that i've tried. However, it does work properly on some other phones and trigger the success block.

Anyone has faced an issue like this before? Any fix that worked? I tried with multiple FakeGPS [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps) but same thing happens in my app when i enable FakeGPS using any of them.

Also, this has started happening recently. It was working fine a couple of months ago.